# How can I access checkbox group named with '[]' end of it

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have group of check boxes named as modules[]. I want to access them through JavaScript. I want to do compare there values with some other values and if they are match check them. Following is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function check_boxes(){
            var chkd_vals = <?php echo json_encode($loaded); ?>;
            for(var i = 0; i < document.modules_form.modules[].length; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < chkd_vals.length; j++){
                    if(chkd_vals[j] == document.modules_form.modules[][i].value){
                        document.modules_form.modules[][i].checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 </script>
```

Above code is not working. How can I possibly do this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
document.modules_form["modules[]"]
```

as you need to keep JS from interpreting the braces as an index.